# Why cant get expected result from database in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, codeigniter

My model like below

```
            $values = array_count_values($books);

            arsort($values);

            $newArray = array_keys($values);

            $views_books_array = array_slice($newArray, 0, 5);

            $result = $this->db->where_in('book_id',$views_books_array)->get('books');

            return $result->result_array();
```

new array will be like below

Array ( [0] => 37 [1] => 28 [2] => 31 [3] => 30 [4] => 38 )

but when i get retrieve data it will get data from randomly not what i have given

im passing book_id to model and controller
my controller like below,

$data['result'] = $this->Book_Model->get_viewed_books($book_id);

if i print_r result will be like

Array ( [0] => 28 [1] => 30 [2] => 31 [3] => 37 [4] => 38 )

like that but i want data according to newArray what did i do wrong

please help me with this anything would appreciated

Comment: why are you ordering with arrays and not using sqls order by clause?

Comment: im taking most viewed books from quaries and storing it in array according to that trying to retrieve from database

Comment: as example my most viewed book in index 0 book id 37 but when i retrieve from sql im getting book id 28 because book name starts in 'A'

Comment: so order by id... there is abs no need to perform a query on the same table twice. example would be if you want to get most viewed books you `ORDER BY id ASC, views ASC`. either way, if you have an sql problem you should have posted the schema and related tables schema

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's an example taken straight from the manual and adapted to your case:

```
<?php
$numbers = array(4, 6, 2, 22, 11); 
sort($numbers);

$arrlength = count($numbers);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
  echo $numbers[$x];
  echo "<br>";
}
```

?>

You can also define this with your query Example are given below :

```
$this->db->order_by('column_name', 'ASC');
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't really anderstand what you want to do but if you want ordered result you can use this method:

```
$this->db->order_by('column', 'order');
```

The second parameter can be: 'ASC' or 'DESC'.
Check the codeigniter [manual](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/).