# How to pass data to same view from two function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function like below

```
public function view($slug = NULL){

        $data['book'] = $this->Book_Model->get_books($slug);
        $data['categories'] = $this->Category_Model->get_categories();

        //current book view
        $book_id = $data['book']['book_id'];
        echo "current book-".$data['book']['book_id']." ";

        if(empty($data['book'])) {
            show_404();
        }

        $this->add_views($book_id);
        $this->get_viewed_books($book_id);

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('books/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');


    }
```

and my **get_viewed_books** function like below

```
public function get_viewed_books($book_id) {

$data['results'] = $this->Book_Model->get_viewed_books($book_id);

}
```

how can I send `$data['results']` to `$this->load->view('books/view', $data);`
with other data from first function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign result of `get_viewed_books` to some key in `$data`:

```
$this->add_views($book_id);
$data['viewed_books'] = $this->get_viewed_books($book_id); // here

$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('books/view', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

Now, in template you have a `viewed_books` variable/key and you can iterate over it.

And of course your `get_viewed_books($book_id)` should **return result**, not assign it to some unknown `$data` variable:

```
public function get_viewed_books($book_id) {
    return $this->Book_Model->get_viewed_books($book_id);
}
```

Comment: sir if you can try this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53183805/why-cant-get-expected-result-from-database-in-codeigniter